# error in mysqli_real_escape_string()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here, i am creating the signing up a new user form but i got a problem in `mysql_real_escape_string()` .so, i used the alternative `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and i tried

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user_name'])
```

but didn`t worked .Here, i have created a separate connect.php(for the connection with the server and database) file in order to save my time  and i have include that file in signup.php file using

```
include 'connect.php';
```

and i am not sure by making separate connect.php file `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user_name'])` can be use or not.

### connect.php

```
<?php
    $server='localhost';
    $username='root';
    $password='';
    $db_name='web_forum_db';

    if(!$conn=mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password))
    {
        exit('Error: could not establish database connection');
    }

    if (!mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name))
     {
        exit('Error: could not select the database');
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

---

### signup.php

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    include 'header.php';
    echo '<h3>Sign up</h3>';
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !='POST')
    {
        echo '<form method="POST" action="">
        Username:<input type="text" name="user_name"/>
        Password: <input type="password" name="user_pass">
        Password again:<input type="password" name="user_pass_check">
        E-mail:<input type="email" name="user_email">
        <input type="submit" value="Add category"/>
        </form>';
    }
    else
    {
        $errors = array();/*declare the array for later use*/
        if(isset($_POST['user_name']))
        {
            //the user name exists
            if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['user_name'])) {
                $errors[]='The username can only contain letters and digits.';
            }

            if(strlen($_POST['user_name'])>30)
            {
                $errors[]='The username cannot be longer than 30 characters.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $errors[]='The username field must not be empty.';
        }
        if(isset($_POST['user_pass']))
        {
            if($_POST['user_pass'] !=$_POST['user_pass_check'])
            {
                $errors[]='The two passwords did not match.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $errors[]='The password field cannot be empty.';
        }
        if (!empty($errors))/*check for  an empty array, if there are errors, they`re in this array*/ {
            echo 'Uh-oh.. a couple of fields are not filled in correctly..';
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($errors as $key => $value)/*walk through the array so all the errors get displayed*/
             {
                echo '<li>' . $value. '</li>';/*This generates a nice error list*/
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_pass,user_email,user_date,user_level) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user_name'])."',
            '".sha1($_POST['user_pass'])."',
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user_email'])."',
            NOW(),0)";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

            if(!$result)
            {
                //something went wrong, display the error

                echo 'Something went wrong while registering. Please try again later.';
                //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Successfully registered. You can now <a href="signin.php">sign in </a> and start posting! :-)';
            }

        }
    }
    include 'footer.php';
?>
```

---

The  showed errors:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\web_forum\signup.php on line 56
>
> Warning: sha1() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\web_forum\signup.php on line 57
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\web_forum\signup.php on line 58
>
> Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\web_forum\signup.php on line 60

The following code lies in line 56,57,58 and 60:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_pass,user_email,user_date,user_level) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user_name'])."',
            '".sha1($_POST['user_pass'])."',
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user_email'])."',
            NOW(),0)";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: use prepared statements instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: or set a variable for the `mysqli_real_eascape_string()` and use the variable for inserting. `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["username"]);`

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your mysqli connection immediately after you establish it.

Just remove this line from `connect.php`:

```
mysqli_close($conn);
```

But anyway, as Jens already said, you should use prepared statements instead of `mysqli_real_escape_query`.